# Matlab vectorization

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I've been trying to vectorize this function for matlab:

```
function [Q,R]=gramSchmidtMod(A)

n=size(A,1);
R=zeros(n);
for j=1:n
    R(j,j)=norm(A(:,j));
    Q(:,j)=A(:,j)/R(j,j);
    for i=j+1:n
        R(j,i)=Q(:,j)'*A(:,i);
        A(:,i)=A(:,i)-Q(:,j)*R(j,i);
    end


end
```

end

i tried:

```
j=1:n
    R(j,j)=norm(A(:,j));
    Q(:,j)=A(:,j)/R(j,j);
     i=j+1:n
        R(j,i)=Q(:,j)'*A(:,i);
        A(:,i)=A(:,i)-Q(:,j)*R(j,i);
```

but that doesn't respect the same order as it would when using two for loops.
Can anyone help me out here ?

Comment: Your last operation is an assignment to A(:,i) which you do not return as an output, then what for? I wouldn't want to provide a vectorization that would end up not giving the right results because the original code was flawed.

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you just use

```
[Q,R]=qr(A)
```